# help on test coverage - new starter

Tags: unit-test

I've been getting my holds on salesforce but stumbled when tried to deploy to a different sandbox as the test coverage was 0%. I realised that this needs to be done and hence my code and test class for the trigger below which just gives me 26% coverage.

```
        trigger OpportunityWeightageRev on Opportunity (before update) {                    
        double prob_diff = 0;                   
        double Nrev = 0; //New revenue                  
        double Orev = 0; //Old revenue                  

        Opportunity OprLast; //Previous opportunity data                    
        //Loop thru to adjust the weighted distribution                 
        for(Opportunity Opr : Trigger.new){                 
            OprLast = Trigger.oldMap.get(Opr.id);                   
            if(OprLast.Probability != opr.Probability){                 
                if(prob_diff==0){                   
                    //Get the percentage difference                 
                    prob_diff = math.abs(OprLast.Probability - opr.Probability);                    
                }                   
                if((opr.Total_Contract_Value__c==0) || (opr.Total_Contract_Value__c==null)) opr.Total_Contract_Value__c = 0;                    
                nrev = opr.Total_Contract_Value__c * (prob_diff/100);                   
                orev = OprLast.Weighted_Revenue__c;                 

                if(orev<>0){                    
                    opr.January__c      = opr.January__c + (nrev / orev) * opr.January__c;      
                    opr.X12_Months__c   = opr.X12_Months__c + (nrev / orev) * opr.X12_Months__c;                    
                }                   
            }                               
        }                   
    }
```

**Test class:**

```
    // Test class for trigger "OpportunityWeightageRev"                     
@isTest                     
public class OpportunityWeightageRev_Test {                     
    static testmethod void OpportunitySave(){                       
        //Creating new opportunity              
        opportunity opr = new opportunity();                        
        // fill the fields                      
        opr.name = 'Test opportunity';                      
        opr.AccountId = '00126000004aWaq';                      
        opr.Area__c = 'New Business';                       
        opr.Sub_Area__c = 'External';                       
        opr.Type = 'FP';                        
        opr.Primary_Location__c = 'London';                     
        opr.StageName = 'Opportunity Qualified';                        
        opr.Start_Date__c = date.today();                       
        opr.CloseDate = date.parse('30/12/2016');                       
        opr.Probability = 30;                       
        //insert the opportunity                        
        insert opr;                     
        // amend for update                     
        opr.StageName = 'Shortlisted';                      
        //update to test the trigger                        
        Test.startTest();                       
        update opr;                         
        Test.stopTest();                        
        Opportunity oprChk = [Select id,StageName,January__c from Opportunity WHERE Id = :opr.Id];                      
        System.assertEquals(0.00,oprChk.January__c);                
    }                       
}
```

below the code coverage hit:

[image]

Any help on this please? Also ONLY when i hit 'Run all' the test coverage is shown as 26% but when i selected the method **initially** to run the test i didnot see anything updated...just 0%...but updated to 26% after "run all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think through your code and what it is doing and requires:

```
if(OprLast.Probability != pr.Probability){
```

means that the probability must change to enter that block so:

Do this:

```
Test.startTest();                       
  pr.Probability = 50;
  update opr;                         
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: yes you are spot on....worked for 48% but i realised the other set of fields are calculated which upon setting some value seems to make it 100% coverage...thk u

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Opportunity Qualified` and `Shortlisted` probabilities aren't the same.

Comment: thkx fernando...now i got how it works.....